# How do I enlarge a small raster logo without losing quality?

Tags: logo, resize, image-quality

A logo has been passed on to me that was made with small dimensions (500px x 300px).  It is not a vector logo and they use paint splatter brushes for the logo.  So now they want the logo to be much larger and I cannot recreate the identical paint splatter effect.  So I need to enlarge but the quality is being lost.

What is the best way to overcome this?

Here is a sample of the logo.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From what you've stated, you're a little stuck for choices. As it's impossible to add pixel quality, improving the quality is tricky.

Personally, in your situation I would print the logo as best as possible, then photography it as best as possible. Some photoshop editing, better quality. If you have a good printer and good camera, you should be good to go.

Comment: thanks, any software that can keep quality?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? If you print it at it's original 500px X 300px then photograph it well, it could be 4000px squared. Edited, you could scale it to whatever size you wanted as you'd potentially never need to go over that large of a size. Keep the original to hand, and try to stay away from editing the colours. I wouldn't touch Hue.

Comment: ok i understand, would i need a HD camera or just good lighting as i am no expert on photography?

Comment: SLR definitely. Good lighting as always, I'd shoot in RAW to get the highest possible quality.

Comment: Have you tried to import the logo to Illustrator and run a Live Trace?  You may not be able to exactly replicate the logo, but with some tweaking, I suspect you can create a vector version that comes _very_ close

Comment: I would have advised live trace IF it was a solid black logo. Since it's multiple colours, the live trace would be poor and not look like the original. Live trace is a good shout though, but better saved for simpler, solid logos.

Comment: I really don't understand the idea of printing something, and scan it again or photograph it... For me it has no sense.

Comment: When a painting needs digital copies, how do you think it is reproduced to the same quality a lot larger? same concept.

Comment: btw what does shoot in RAW mean?

Comment: How could you keep the orginal colors using your method?

Comment: RAW is an image type, like JPG. Good camera's have this ability and the quality is much greater and truer to the content.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it for a web-page or a ruff sketch it is ok, if you want to print it you should not use it.

Well, you can, but it would only be "good" at a certain width (1 to 3 cm i guess).

I would suggest NOT to redraw it in Illustrator as you always ALTER it, which is never a good idea.

In such cases you have to contact your client(?) to get a useable Version of the Logo, either vector based (BEST!) or in high resolution. Otherwise you would not be able to produce decent quality. (I speak of printing...)

Answer (score 0):

There are some resizing programs that have diferent algorithms than the tipical bicubic.

The main diference is that this kind of programs try to preserve the sharp edges between colours (the bicubic aproach is to soften the borders) so, in this case becouse the type of gaphic could work.

They don't perform miracles, but can help you to enlarge the image lets say 300%.

Here are 2 that I have used, but there are plenty more.

Photo Zoom http://www.benvista.com/photozoompro

Reshade http://reshade.com/

Here is a post, written in spanish with some tests, auto translated in google https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?act=url&depth=1&hl=es&ie=UTF8&prev=_t&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=es&tl=en&u=http://forobeta.com/diseno-grafico/359857-programas-ampliar-imagenes-algoritmos.html&usg=ALkJrhjGqb1yXEf17Hdkm7B2URpUycJL8w

1) Before trying to enlarge them I would clean a bit the image, enhance a bit the colours and clean any jpg artifacts.

2) Test diferent algorithms untill I find something decent. Don't force the resizing too much. I would recomend 300% max.

3) Sharpen a bit the final result.

4) Think the posibility to vectorize this result.

5) Clean and optimize this vectorized version. This could work as a "new version" and the client should consider having this vectorized version as the "official" logo.

But at the end there is no way of resizing a bitmap in a magical way.